# Ubuntu One: why do I get an Account Status Error?

Tags: 12.04, windows-8

My Ubuntu One account has displayed the following for several days now:

> We are sorry, but while our system updates your account, you cannot
>   see details of or make changes to your subscriptions.
>
> This can take up to two hours to complete, but in the meantime you can
>   use your new services.

Comment: I should fill in the form [here for Ubuntu One customer support](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/) and you should get a response.